# Custom Font Issue on Iphone

Tags: iphone, css, fonts

I have a website in which i have used a custom font in css it works fine on PC but on mobiles like Iphone that font does not load. Any idea how can that be enabled on all mobile devices?

I will appreciate your answers in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Safari, for reasons unknown, doesn't support the WOFF, TTF/OTF or EOT font formats desktop browsers do. For iPhone compatibility you must also include an SVG version of the font in the sources list, along with all the others.

This is an annoyance (we can only hope that in future Apple will standardise on WOFF like everyone else), but tools like [FontSquirrel's](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) will include this for you.